# getting node port is undefined even though i don't see anything listening on the ports

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I currently have a node.js backend going with express to serve my routes. I have the port in my `.env` file as shown below

```
NODE_ENV = development
port = 7000
```

Now when I try to run my backend, the port is not available. I run the commands below to check but I don't get any output from the terminal

```
lsof -i:7000
lsof -i:8080
```

I am not sure what's holding the ports. I will paste my `server.js` below for reference also.

```
import express from 'express'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import colors from 'colors'

dotenv.config()

const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
if (!process.env.PORT) {
    console.log(`Port is unavailalbe ${PORT}`)
    process.exit(1);
} else {
    app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server is running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} on port ${PORT}`.yellow.bold));
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the issue is how `port` is capitalized in your `.env` file?

Comment: thanks, @richytong that was the reason. If there was a way to mark your comment as an answer, I would.

Comment: I defer to @metalcamp's answer :-)

Comment: Thank you kind stranger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have variable `port` in `.env` but you're checking if `PORT` is defined (which is not). Change `port` to `PORT` in `.env`.

Edit: I also recommend removing spaces in `.env`.

Comment: as soon as I can accept your answer (in 4 minutes) I will. Thanks a lot!